# Is angularjs recommended for large scale authentication based applications?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, security, authentication

It has been some time now that i am learning and using angularjs framework, and although some of it's features are truly awesome, it seems to me as if it's key features are a bit problematic for authentication based applications.

Let's look at an example. Let's say i have a website that has a user login, and once the user is logged in he can click on a link to his/hers dashboard page. On the dashboard the user can see some private data. Now, the way i'm used to do it, is run some script on the server side and then if a user is connected, return some HTML, if no then redirect the user to another location. The way angularjs encourages me to do it is by using the route feature, say like this:

```
when('/dashboard', {
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
    controller: 'DashboardController'
  })
```

This way, in case a user is not connected, angularjs will first fetch the template HTML, then the controller will fetch some data and receive an authentication error, then redirect the route to another location. To me it seems like a worse solution for more than one reason:

1) First of all, my HTML gets exposed to everyone. Although this isn't devastating, it just seems like a bad security practice (imagine that you do not even have a facebook account, but still you can see all of facebook pages HTML, and even worse, all the objects and fields of the like for example user.accessToken).

2) I would make a larger number of requests to the server, first one to fetch the template, second for authentication validation and data, third and probably fourth for the redirection. I assume angularjs cache the templates so maybe the actual number of requests is smaller than i mentioned, still, dealing with all this on the server side is only one request - and like angularjs, it can also not load the entire page but only the needed HTML throw AJAX. My case here is arguable, but still, something about it seems wrong.

3) This is maybe the most important issue for me. Everything i do on the server side has to be pasted on the client side. For example, the routing feature must be clear on the server side as will as on the client side - in case the user enters directly to some inner page in my application, or through routing in the application links. This means that every time a change something in my routing configuration, i have to do it once in the server side, and once in the client side - which also seems to me like a bad practice and modularity of my code.

Is angularjs not recommended for these kind of applications? Should i use angularjs features that complement my applications (like controllers, variable binding and so on) but disregard and ones that doesn't (like routing)?

Do i look at it the wrong way?

Comment: I have exactly same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't looking at it the wrong way, just from a different perspective. You aren't use to developing SPA's so this is normal.

1) Sure HTML gets exposed to everyone, but that is just a template. It just contains the html template, not the specific data related to everyones facebook profile. The server controls the data that is returned to the user and it would only return the data that the user had access to see. Really this is no different to a non SPA except for the amount of data that is sent back and forth.

2) For a normal app you would first have to request the login page, then the data would be posted to the server and then a redirect would occur. This is 3 requests. With angular it would be one for the first load, second for the login view template, then third to post login data, then fourth to get the main logged in view and fifth for data required for the view. This is only two more. After that to login, if the user clicks log out and then login again it would only be two requests vs three, or if they close the tab and come back it would be 3 requests. In other words it's not that much difference. For most scenarios it will be the same amount of requests, if not less after caching.

3) The way routing works in a SPA is it only happens on the client. There is no need to have it also on the server. Just re-write the url for all request to return index.html and then angular routing will take care of the rest.

In regards to it being recommended. There are really no such recommendations. It's up to you. There are advantages and disadvantages with both. Most of the disadvantages of Angular would be related to learning curve.

Comment: It was some time ago but in retrospective I think this answer helped me the most

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do look at it the wrong way. You mix up client- and server side issues.

Your proposed solution for authentication is, as you already said so yourself, bad from a security point of view. Delivering your HTML to the user although he/she is not authenticated is a bad idea.

**Authentication always has to be done on the server side.** Do not ever trust the client. That's why when you have have an unauthenticated user requesting your restricted-access `dashboard.html`, you sent back some HTTP error (typically 401 or 403, depending whether the user is unauthenticated or not authorized). This way, an unauthenticated user will never see the `dashboard.html` and your problems 1 and 2 are solved.

Your point 3 is another matter, but also invalid. There is no reason why your client and server side should have the same routing features. Routing should be up to the client-side in most circumstances. E.g., if your user manually enters `http:://mydomain.org/subsite`, the server redirects him to `http:://mydomain.org`, where AngularJS uses the appropriate routing.

So your points are not really about AngularJS being a problem for applications requiring authentication. As a matter of fact, there are many web apps out there with authentication using AngularJS. So as conclusion: **No, you can use AngularJS as much as any other JavaScript technology for authenticated sites**. However, if it is "recommended" (for your project) is another matter, which depends on many more factors and is beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: how we can prevent show that template? (dashboard.html)

Comment: @mhadadi It depends on which web server you use. However, the documentation of your web server should include that (if not, I am sure there already is a question about this on SO, if you don't use same super-bizarre web server)